# Константы, вопросик.

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview, uiview

**Здравствуйте**

Можно сделать так, чтобы если UITextView расширялся по высоте, тогда и расширялся UIView который содержит сам UITextView?

Константы то я поставил, чтобы определенный UIView был всегда внизу, клавиатура не помеха. Кодом можно расширить по высоте только один элемент, если сразу два расширять -- ничего не выйдет, они друг друга каким-то образом перебивают, и в итоге расширяется только один элемент. В константах я не очень разбираюсь, только сейчас начал разбираться как их правильно юзать.

Выходит такая проблема:
[image: ios]

Сам UITextView расширяется по высоте, но благодаря упертости UIView он не пускает вниз, а берет под себя.

Comment: Не уверен, что получится такое реализовать константами. я бы предложил прицепить KVO и расширять родителя, когда увеличивается child

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko есть какие-то примеры? Ссылки на что-то подобное?

Answer (score 1):

Через KVO это будет выглядеть примерно так

Создать обсервер

```
[self.childView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

обработать

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context
{
    self.parentView.frame = self.childView.frame;
    //self.parentView.frame = [(UITextView*)object frame];
}
```

не забыть убрать

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.childView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"];
}
```